# how to center a modal window on the screen and not the site itself

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, tailwind-css

I added a dialog box to my project that is in the header component, and when clicked I need it to be displayed in the center, even if the page was scrolled down.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default function ResponsiveDialog({ classes }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open responsive dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen={fullScreen}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        PaperProps={{
          elevation: 0,
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle id="responsive-dialog-title">
          {"Use Google's location service?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending
            anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose}>
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEBJ1.jpg)

In simple words, I want the modal window to appear in the center if the page is scrolled down, here is a fragment from the video https://youtu.be/DeVSpye-aUI

If the modal window is set to a maximum height of 100 vh, then the component will be fixed in the center, but if you scroll down and click on the modal window, the page will scroll up to this modal window.

Comment: The reason is in your css code which is absent in your question. Please add css code and try to simplify your code in the question body or just add sandbox.